# Insert video on web page from Google Drive using <video> HTML5 Tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, html5-video

My web page have problem into the loading because of a video into the header that is important for the beauty of the page. The page load pretty fast but my server have a TTFB of like 4/5s when loading the video. So i uploaded the video into my Google Drive ad I set the permission for everyone with the link. But the video is not loaded the device without my google account.

This are the permissions for the video from google drive.
[Permissions on google drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOH87.png)
After that i linked to the video from the php file of the homepage. With some other link in case the first fail.

```
<video id="fp-slider-video" <?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $video_atts)); ?> poster="https://www.villabentivogliomarche.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/frist_frame-1.png">

                    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1D3eUcSeRTgPB3weoUHyFoEO4qfhWjpMb" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="https://github.com/Andrea-Dambrosio/collegamentoLDVForum-Drive/blob/main/Villa%20Bentivoglio%20DRONE%20-%20O%20(online-video-cutter.com)%20(1)%20(3).mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="https://www.villabentivogliomarche.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Villa-Bentivoglio-DRONE-O-online-video-cutter.com-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">

                    You browser don't support video.

                </video>
```

The video is loaded super fast from my personal browser. The GitHub link don't work anywhere and on other devices the video is loaded directly from my server:

`https://www.villabentivogliomarche.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Villa-Bentivoglio-DRONE-O-online-video-cutter.com-1.mp4`

But is really really slow and is a bad user experience.
Why the video is not loaded from google drive everywhere, the file permission is for everyone.

Comment: I don't think an embedded video would affect TTFB. The TTFB is the time for the full HTML to make it to browser. Look at https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/1950766/how-do-i-embed-videos-from-my-google-drive-google-photos-into-a-blogger-post-embed-is-no-more?hl=en for how to embed from Google Drive, I dont think that will fix your issue though. Usually TTFB is server side code issue (e.g. PHP), server to browser, not browser to get all resources. All resources I think is called full paint load, or something like that

Comment: This is the timing for the load of the video from my server: https://imgur.com/gIFdyyb .
This is the timing for the load of the video from google drive (but don't work everywhere) : https://imgur.com/3NUjKe6

Comment: @AndreaD'Ambrosio **(1)** Use H264 (not current H265) as the video codec. Then it will display in all major browsers.  **(2)** You need to put metadata at the front for a fast picture display. Normally MP4 puts its metadata at the back of the file. MP4 was not designed for online streaming. Solution: Re-encode video as an MP4 containing H264 video codec. Find an option like _"MP4 fast start"_ or _"Optimize for the web"_ and enable it. Otherwise find a tool to fix the metadata. Search on Google for keywords: `MP4 fast start fix moov box front`

Comment: I'll try, thanks.